# Navigation in Vaadin Flow App behind a reverse proxy that rewrites the url path

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, reverse-proxy, vaadin-flow

I want to run multiple Vaadin Applications (Vaadin Flow 14) as microservices behind a reverse proxy. Lets call them `app1` and `app2`. Both have their Servlet configured by default, so map to `/*`.
Now the reverse proxy forwards them

```
/app1/rest/of/path -> app1:/rest/of/path
/app2/rest/of/path -> app2:/rest/of/path
```

But when someone uses navigation or `navigateTo` inside `app1` or `app2` it breaks, as they do not know about the prefix (`app1` or `app2` respectively) that should be added.
How can I configure the Servlet in a Vaadin Spring setup so, that it automatically gets this prefix. Or are there even more elegant solutions (like rewriting the navigation method?).

Thanks!

Comment: any insights here?